# buildozer can't download hostpython2

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I'm new to kivy. when i type `buildozer -v android debug`, buildozer can't download hostpython2. I searched this error but haven't found a solution yet.

**OS:** Ubuntu 17.04

Below is the error message, can anyone help me to fix the problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
[INFO]:    # Downloading recipes 
[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/tanberk/İndirilenler/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/tanberk/İndirilenler/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> running basename http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2                                                                                          
[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython2 from http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1698, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1908, in open_https
    return self._open_generic_http(self._https_connection, url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1857, in _open_generic_http
    http_conn.request("GET", selector, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1261, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 385, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 760, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 996, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 641, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:720)
```

Comment: Since you are using Python 3.x, please replace hostpython2 with hostpython3.

Comment: thanks but how can i do this? when i type `buildozer -v android debug`, hostpython2 is automatically downloaded.

Comment: You don't want to replace hostpython2 with hostpython3, that isn't relevant. The issue appears to relate only to downloading hostpython2. Are you able to visit the url that it's trying to download from in a web browser?

Comment: Now i am trying to follow the steps that given in https://github.com/kivy/buildozer

Comment: hostpython2 doesn't give an error after applied the steps that given in https://github.com/kivy/buildozer, but now the six package gives the same SSL error.

Comment: @inclement yes i visited the url and the file was downloaded without a problem.